# Why does a Mac webcam not report any supported video formats when queried with Silverlight 4?

Tags: silverlight, macos, silverlight-4.0, webcam

I'm testing some Silverlight 4 code to connect to webcams to grab video and audio. Everything works fine on PC's, but on Macs it appears that when querying the webcam for the supported video formats, no data is returned when using VideoCaptureDevice.SupportedFormats call. I have tried this using both an external webcam as well as a built in iSight camera

When looking at the Silverlight preferences on the Mac, I can see the webcam and it shows the video so I know it's hooked up properly and working.

I should mention that the similar query (AudioCaptureDevice.SupportedFormats) for audio formats does work.

Doe anybody know what might cause this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, that's embarrassing.  [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.videocapturedevice.supportedformats%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) shows that OSX will always return this as empty, now off to work around that...

Comment: Out of curiosity, did you ever come up with a decent workaround?

Comment: Not yet, no. Sadly MSDN seems to indicate that this is still the case with Silverlight 5.

Comment: By the way, I did figure out that if I just pass in the format that I'd prefer, Silverlight will choose a format that's reasonably close. Of course, it's not guaranteed to be exactly the same, so I needed to be able to handle whatever format it handed me, not just the format I preferred, but that's not excessively difficult...